# iOS itunesconnect sandbox test account (Invalid Year)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-sandbox

This is so weird! last week I created a test user account and it was just fine but today, it is asking me for adding birth year! as you see in the below screenshot. there's no year field to fill in and it is asking for it?! Apple, are you serious? if I'm doing something wrong, please tell me...

[image]

**UPDATE:** it seems like it was a bug on apple's page. it worked just now. I lost two days though!

Comment: I am seeing exactly the same thing on the live iTunes Connect sign-in, when being asked to put in details for a new account.

Comment: @DuncanBabbage is it a bug on apple's side you think? I couldn't find any other having this problem after a lot of searching and Googling!

Comment: I'd say so. Particularly as it appears in two unrelated pages that are underpinned by their sign-in/sign-up technology. I also tried in Safari and Chrome and no difference.

Comment: yeah, I also tried with Safari, Chrome and Firefox :(

Comment: Reported to Apple as Bug ID 22452575. You might want to do the same. https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I am having the same issue. I reported it to Apple as well.

Comment: Having the exact same issue here.

Comment: +1 same issue. I guess apple are in the process of updating the sandbox test user form to include year. Currently, testing with a sandbox user does require year but it is requested when signing in the first time, as the user on your device. This is definitely a more streamlined approach but why on earth implement validation before the input box. WHY APPLE!

Comment: I've just ran into just the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary bug in itunesconnect between 27th and 30th of August.

Same problem also mentioned in

- ["Invalid year" error when setting up Sandbox Tester Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248792/invalid-year-error-when-setting-up-sandbox-tester-account)
- [iTunesConnect unable to accept invitation - Invalid Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244133/itunesconnect-unable-to-accept-invitation-invalid-year)