# iTunesConnect unable to accept invitation - Invalid Year

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've been invited to my client's iTunes Connect but I'm unable to submit the profile/acceptance form. It's complaining about an Invalid Year (presumably in relation to the DOB) but the form only asks for month and day! I've tried various combinations but no luck.

It seems like an Apple bug to me but is it something that people have managed to get around?

Comment: could be american and the month and day are swapped around?

Comment: Try logging in with Safari if you're not already doing so. I often find iTunesConnect website only works with Safari.

Comment: The fields are the wrong way round (Month/Day) ;) _but_ are definitely "Month" and "Day" (not year).

Comment: @Columbo Same result I'm afraid (I've now tested using Safari & Chrome)

Comment: got this too, using both Safari and Chrome. need help!

Comment: Same problem here. Tested Chrome & Safari. Come on Apple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, they've now sorted the bug. A year field has been added to the form. I guess the validation code was somehow deployed before the code for the field.

Comment: Did you have to do anything for it to appear? It's still not appearing for me.

Comment: You can create now user, there is no field added but also is not validated now

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this seems like an issue with Apple. Hopefully, it will be resolved shortly...

[Invalid Year 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248792/invalid-year-error-when-setting-up-sandbox-tester-account)

[Invalid Year 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243705/ios-itunesconnect-sandbox-test-account-invalid-year)

There seem to have been a couple of bugs submitted to Apple about this, so I hope this means it will be resolved soon.

Comment: Yeah, these are a little different as this isn't a sandbox user issue but I guess they use the same (broken) validation for both.