# Error creating user in iTunes Connect: Invalid Year

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm just creating a new Sandbox user in iTunnes Connect and this is not my first time. But there I get an error 'invalid year' when in the form is not any 'Year' field ??
I looking for it even in the html but didn't find it. Where can be the problem?

**UPDATE** (31.8.2015): The field 'Year' don't exist in the form, but now is possible create the user.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some bug related to this at Apple side, which I think will be resolved soon

Check this

[iTunesConnect unable to accept invitation - Invalid Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244133/itunesconnect-unable-to-accept-invitation-invalid-year)

and this

["Invalid year" error when setting up Sandbox Tester Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248792/invalid-year-error-when-setting-up-sandbox-tester-account/32248957#32248957)

Comment: Thank you! I also let the message in the Apple Support Communities. So soon they solve it I will update the message ;)

Comment: I opened a support case with the iTunes Connect team yesterday - I got a reply saying they're investigating. Should be today hopefully