# "Invalid year" error when setting up Sandbox Tester Account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, appstore-sandbox

Getting a strange error when setting up Sandbox Tester in iTunesConnect. For some reason, iTunesConnects throws an error: "Invalid year". It looks like this:

[image]

Oddly I cannot specify a year because it only asks me for month and day:

[image]

I don't use the same email I used when creating apple ID and I don't have any +abc in my email address. I tried with gmail.com and hotmail.com but the result was the same in both cases. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also heard about it, not able to check it right now, check this also [iTunesConnect unable to accept invitation - Invalid Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244133/itunesconnect-unable-to-accept-invitation-invalid-year)

Comment: thanks but nothing helpful there. I also tried with Safari, didnt work either.

Comment: Yes i want to let you know that may be there is some bug in it from apple side.